# How to access variables in terragrunt.hcl file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt, terraform-template-file

I am trying to access variables from variables.tf file inside terragrunt.hcl file.

Project structure:

```
| Terraform
    | shared-folder
        - variables.tf
    -vars.tf
    -terragrunt.hcl
```

This is the code snippet from .hcl file

```
locals{
    
    account_vars = "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/variables.tf"
    
    env = local.account_vars.locals.account_name
    
}

remote_state {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket         = get_env("STATEFILE_BUCKET", "terragrunt-${get_aws_account_id()}-statefiles")
    key            = "jsworld/state/jsTutorial-${local.env}.tfstate"
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
locals {
  account_name   = "devl"
}
```

How can I access this into .hcl file

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? To access which file? And from where?

Comment: I want to access variables from variables.tf file into terragrunt.hcl

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Terragrunt works. Terragrunt is able to instantiate TF variables and pass values into Terraform and to read the outputs from Terraform.